# How can i ask Tomcat to take my enhanced for OpenJPA classes?

Tags: tomcat, ant, openjpa

I have a problem caused by a lack of knowledge.
I use OpenJPA as JPA implementation and Tomcat server to run my application, also I use Idea12 as ide.

I have a task - provide open jpa enhancement at build - time.
To achieve that, first of all I deny OpenJPA to enhance entities at runtime by adding this property to my persistence.xml:

```
<property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported"/>
```

Now OpenJPA won't enhance classes at runtime, as I wish.

After that, I write a target for enhancement in my ant-build.xml. It works fine, and creates /build directory with compiled classes. If I look at compiled classe code, I see there additional fields for OpenJPA - pcStateManager and other. Ok, that's great.

And now the problem - when I start Tomcat via Idea, it doesn't take my enhanced classes. I guess Tomcat doesn't even know, that I enhanced my classes. Seems that he compiles the code again, and start application with unenhanced classes. And for sure, there is an exception, when I start to work with the database.

So, is it possible to configure Tomcat, so he cat take my classes from /build directory?

P.S. I also tried to use some Idea plugins for enhancement, but they did not solve the problem - I had the same exception, that classes are unenhanced.

**upd** Both two enhance idea plugins : OpenJPA enhancer and Data Nucleas Integration with OpenJPA extension do not solve the problem. So that makes me think, that something just goes wrong. Maybe the main problem are tomcat settings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested - here is the solution :

1. you need to open you Idea # Project Structure and choose the module, that contains your classes
2. you need to switch the "output" property from "Inherit project compile output" to "Use module compile output path" and specify the directory with your enhanced classes
3. thats all, now when Tomcat will build the WAR file, he will take your enhanced classes. Good luck.